# Convert numbers to words easy

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I'm new at programming and Im trying to learn Python.

Im trying to make a program that converts numbers into the word for the number. Ex 15 would be "fifteen".

In the moment Im making a small function that only treats numbers between 10-20. I've begun with this code:

```
listatva=["tio","elva","tolv","tretton","fjorton","femton","sexton","sjutton","arton","nitton"]
def dole(y):
    if 10<=y<20:
        y=listatva[y-1]
        print y

    return

dole(15)
```

But when im running the code I get a message saying :IndexError: list index out of range.

I dont get it. Can someon please explane?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is   in `y = listatva[y-1]`, you  run your function as `dole(15)` where `y = 15`.

So  `15 - 1 = 14` and you only have `ten` elements in your list.

Therefore  `listatva[14]`  is going to give you an `IndexError`.

Try using modulo:  `y = listatva[y%10]`

`15 % 10 = 5`,  `listatva[5] == "femton"`, btw I have no idea what language "femton" is, I am just presuming it means `15` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `dict` not a `list`. e.g.

```
d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

>>> d[1]
'one'
```